# I really need help installing vundle for neovim

Tags: linux, vim

I've been  trying to get neovim running with vundle for two months or so without success.

I'll try to make this a little detailed to make it easier for you to understand what I've done so far.

Linux Mint 19.1

- Installed Neovim + Git for Git clone
- Than I run 
  `git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`
- Located .vimrc file in "/usr/share/vim"
- put in all the stuff required starting with

```
    set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
    filetype off                  " required

    " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
    set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

- Also created a .vimrc file in "/home" directory and put the same stuff inside as in the past step

Problem: When I start Neovim and try to execute :PluginInstall, I get the error

> E492 no editor command.

I don't know what went wrong here. 
Hope somebody could help me with this :)

Answer (score 4):

You also need to source the `.vimrc` from your neovim initiator. Nvim normally uses `$HOME/.config/nvim/init.vim`, rather than `.vimrc`. Add `source /usr/share/vim/.vimrc` to the nvim init file.

I would also suggest putting in your **user folder**, not `/home`, but `/home/[username]`.

If that fails, ensure you are sourcing the file with your vundle code. Add this code to the file:
`echom "loaded vimrc"`

Then load neovim, and type `:messages`. If the line added above doesn't appear, then the file isn't being read. If that's the case, type `:e $MYVIMRC` and add the code into the file that appears.